Question About the Antiderivative of $x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$
Since the function $f(x) := x \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is continuous everywhere, there is an antiderivative $F(x)$. This should theoretically be continuous, as it must be differentiable. However, if I output the graph of this in Wolfram Alpha or other programs such as GeoGebra, the graph in the $0$ looks anything but continuous. Is this a numerical/graphical error?


The error is not numerical, it's symbolic. The antiderivative is erroneously calculated. But the graphic of the (wrong) antiderivative is correct.

I think the issue is $x \sin(1/x)$ is undefined at $x=0$, so the antiderivative it gives you is only valid on $x \ne 0$, and on that domain it is indeed continuous.

@arkeet You can continue the function $f (x) = x \cdot \sin(1/x)$ continuously to 0. The value is simple $f(0) = 0$. Thus this can not be the problem.

@jjagmath Thank you for your answer, but this root function is also the answer from Wolfram Alpha. So it can't be completely wrong, can it? Does this perhaps only apply to a certain range? Maybe I should look into it more. Thank you very much.

Why people think that Wolfram Alpha knows everything? It's NOT an omnipotent oracle that knows the answer to every mathematical question.

Mathematica gives the same antiderivative:  Integrate[x  Sin[1/x], x] results in 1/2 x Cos[1/x] + 1/2 x^2 Sin[1/x] + 1/2 SinIntegral[1/x].  Taking the derivative of that result and simplifying (D[1/2  x  Cos[1/x] + 1/2 x^2 Sin[1/x] + 1/2  SinIntegral[1/x], x] // FunctionExpand // Expand) results in x Sin[1/x].  It is better to call this "an" antiderivative rather than "the" antiderivative.

Strictly speaking, your function $f$ is not continuous everywhere, because it is undefined at 0.  However, the singularity at 0 is removable.  The function
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
x \sin(1/x), &\text{if }x \ne 0,\\
0, &\text{if } x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous everywhere.
It looks like you asked GeoGebra for an indefinite integral of the function $f$.  Remember that there are infinitely many indefinite integrals on any interval on which the function is continuous, and to get the general formula for an antiderivative on an interval you have to add "$+\, C$" to any antiderivative.  Geogebra gave you a formula that gives an antiderivative on each of the intervals $(0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$.  You can add "$+\,C_1$" on one of those intervals and "$+\,C_2$" on the other to get the general formula for a function whose derivative is $f(x)$ at all $x \ne 0$.  To get something that works at $x=0$ as well, you have to choose $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that the singularity at 0 becomes removable, and then remove the singularity by defining the function at $x=0$.

That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.

$f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ is undefined at $x=0$, but if you define $f(0) = 0$ you get a continuous function on the real line.  However, on the complex plane the singularity at $x=0$ is not removable: it is an essential singularity.  An antiderivative, valid for $x \ne 0$, is
$$ \frac{x^2 \sin(1/x) + x \cos(1/x) + \text{Si}(1/x)}{2} $$
where $\text{Si}$ is the "sine integral function",
$$ \text{Si}(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \; dt $$
However, note that $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \text{Si}(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\; dt = \frac{\pi}{2} $$
while $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \text{Si}(x) =\int_0^{-\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\; dt = - \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\; dt = - \frac{\pi}{2}$$
The result is that our antiderivative has a discontinuity at $x=0$.
It's not really a question of Wolfram Alpha choosing a "wrong formula": the antiderivative is valid for all nonzero complex numbers, and its value on the negative reals is the unique analytic continuation of the value on the positive reals. Wolfram Alpha doesn't "know" that you don't care about complex numbers and want an antiderivative that can be extended to be continuous on the real line.

$$I=\int x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx=-\int \frac{\sin (t)}{t^3} \,dt$$ Use two integrations by parts to obtain
$$I=\frac{\sin(t)}{2 t^2}+\frac{\cos (t)}{2 t}+\frac{\text{Si}(t)}{2}$$
Back to $x$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2} x \cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\text{Si}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ which is undefined if $x=0$.
But, asymptotically $I\to \frac \pi 4$ when $x\to 0^+$ and $I\to -\frac \pi 4$ when $x\to 0^-$
Checking numerically for $x=10^{-k}$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \text{value} \\
 1 & 0.7845001151 \\
 2 & 0.7853990095 \\
 3 & 0.7853981640 \\
 4 & 0.7853981634 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
